# Adding a CUPS printing server filter

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi3, cups

So I just got a raspberry pi with the intention to make my Rollo label printer wireless. I installed Raspbian and PrintNode, but when it came down to downloading the Rollo driver onto the device I couldn't because it expects an 86_64x cpu and mine is armv71.

I inspected the .ppd and found that the main issue was a failed filter, bc Rollo is trying to use a filter that cups cannot find.

Is there a way to just copy a filter into CUPS? how do I add a custom filter so CUPS can find it and I can use my printer?

Answer (score 0):

I've been hunting this down trying to solve the exact same problem for a bit now and have come to the conclusion that it's not possible unless one of these things happens:

- <strike>Rollo releases a filter that's been compiled for the ARM arch.</strike>
- <strike>Someone reverse engineers the compiled filter to recompile it for ARM.</strike>
- <strike>Rollo releases the filter source code so we can compile our own for the RPi (ie. ARM).</strike>

**Update: Rollo released a beta RPi driver here:** https://www.rollo.com/driver-dl/beta/rollo-driver-raspberrypi-beta.zip

The first two seem the most unlikely. The third seems possible and I think I'll ask them to do just that... but who knows how they view their IP.

That said, I punted for a small fanless (well, it *had* a fan...) Celeron micropc that runs Ubuntu x86_64 until the Rollo filter comes out for ARM. Good luck!

Comment: ah thanks for your comment Dan! I ended up going with a small computer that runs windows I got on amazon.